# Embeded Windows Media Player full screen

Tags: c#, winforms, fullscreen, axwindowsmediaplayer

I have an embedded video in a winform using `axwindowsmediaplayer` and C#.

I have a timer to set the control to `fullscreen=true` after some time.

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Stop();
    videowmp.fullScreen = true;
}
```

I use a database to get the videos, and I call a function to obtain them every time the video finishes, for some reason I needed a second timer there to start the new video:

```
private void videowmp_PlayStateChange(object sender,
    AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.newState == 8)
    {
        timer2.Interval = 100;
        timer2.Enabled = true;
    }
}

private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer2.Enabled = false;
    selec_video();
}
```

The function `selec_video()` gets the video, set the URL for the windows media player control and set it to `play()`.

My problem is that when a video finishes, I lose full-screen mode. I mean the video goes back to its original size. I tried to set `fullscreen=true` after calling `selec_video()`, but I got an error (catastrophic error). I suppose this happens because the control is already in full screen... So what I want to do, is call `selec_video()`, without losing the full-screen mode.

Answer (score 3):

The below code is checking your media player's play state. If it's playing something, it will set it to full screen mode.

```
private void timer2_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     selec_video(); 
     if (videowmp.playState == WMPLib.WMPPlayState.wmppsPlaying)
     {
        videowmp.fullScreen = true;
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use PlayStateChange action. And also you can find other state codes from [PlayStateChange Event of the AxWindowsMediaPlayer Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd562460(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
private void axWindowsMediaPlayer1_PlayStateChange(object sender, AxWMPLib._WMPOCXEvents_PlayStateChangeEvent e)
{
     if (e.newState == 3)//Playing
     {
           axWindowsMediaPlayer1.fullScreen = true;                
     }

}
```